# Miktex \extractpdftexversion has an extra }

Tags: miktex

I have an overleaf project created using this [template](https://github.com/GarenSidonius/ASU-Dissertation-Template). The project compiles without any error on Overleaf, but when I try to compile on my local machine using MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.3 (MiKTeX 21.1) it gives an error as shown below:

```
! Argument of \extractpdftexversion has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11     \extractpdftexversion\pdftexbanner\@nil}
```

Below is an MWE that reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,             
               oneside,                 
               12pt]                    
               {memoir}

\ifpdf                                  % Build pdf creator string (for pdfTeX)
  \makeatletter
  \def\extractpdftexversion#1-#2-#3 #4%
    \@nil{#3}
  \edef\pdfcreator{pdfTeX \expandafter%
    \extractpdftexversion\pdftexbanner\@nil}
  \makeatother
\fi
\ifxetex                                % Build pdf creator string (for XeTeX)
  \edef\pdfcreator{XeTeX %
    \the\XeTeXversion\XeTeXrevision}
\fi
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I tried replacing `\extractpdftexversion\pdftexbanner\@nil}` with `\extractpdftexversion{\pdftexbanner\@nil}}` but it did not work.

Comment: The miktex banner says `This is MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.3.0 (1.40.21)` . There is only one hyphen and so your argument template `#1-#2-#3 #4`  doesn't work. The texlive banner says `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)...`

Comment: What should I do to fix it then?

Comment: I would use `\the\pdftexversion`  if I wanted the version.

Comment: Can you please be more clear and say what exactly should I replace and where?

Comment: if you want to fill the /Producer entry in the pdf, simply do nothing at all. miktex will write by default `/Producer (MiKTeX pdfTeX-1.40.21)` and texlive `/Producer (pdfTeX-1.40.21)`.

Comment: i am just banging my head in the wall